# jinja2 import Markup error while working with Flaask Modal

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

First, note that I'm not trying to import Markup. I am trying to render a bootstrap modal with flask, after going through the documentation on PYPI about it...
I'm making use of the

```
from flask_modals.modal import Modal
```

and all with the documentation [Here](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Modals/) However, I get an error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Osondu\PycharmProjects\ecommerceSite\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_modals.modal import Modal
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Osondu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_modals\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_modals.modal import (
  File "C:\Users\Samuel Osondu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_modals\modal.py", line 5, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (C:\Users\Samuel Osondu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py)
```

I've been trying to fix this for hours now, i've tried:

1. Updating my Jinja
2. Installing the Markup
3. I've even changed the environment

Yet nothing, I sincerely do need help.

Comment: You should accept your answer since you sorted your problem out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of hassle, I finally found a way through it.
The problem was actually coming from the flask file despite running on the current flask version.

I guess the flask_modal depended on the Markup package to run regardless of the fact that I didn't need to import it to run my code and as such...
I clicked the location to the file

```
File "C:\Users\Samuel Osondu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\flask_modals\modal.py", line 5, in <module>
```

Then I changed the from  `from jinja2 import Markup`
to `from markupsafe import Markup` and this worked just fine!!